# in Windows,Docker Deploy .net core and have not execute rightly

Tags: docker

at my windows envioroment,I want to run .net core program with docker,I have modify docker file as following:

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest 
WORKDIR /appp
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]

when I make port mapping,it come out not right result as following
[image]

why port 5000 change to 80,can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The base image `microsoft/aspnetcore` [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/~/dockerfile/) is defining the environment variable `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80`

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-preview1-runtime

# set up network
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80

# set up the runtime store
ENV ASPNETCORE_RUNTIME_STORE_VERSION 2.0.0-preview1
RUN curl -o /tmp/runtimestore.tar.gz \
    https://dist.asp.net/packagecache/${ASPNETCORE_RUNTIME_STORE_VERSION}/linux-x64/aspnetcore.runtimestore.tar.gz \
    && export DOTNET_HOME=$(dirname $(readlink $(which dotnet))) \
    && tar -x -C $DOTNET_HOME -f /tmp/runtimestore.tar.gz \
    && rm /tmp/runtimestore.tar.gz
```

Override the variable in your Dockerfile or expose and map port 80